# How to View Data (for Scraping) of Interactive Graph with Hover

Tags: web-scraping, screen-scraping

I would like to scrape an interactive plot that displays different information based on where the pointer is hovering. This website is what I am interested in:https://embed.chartblocks.com/1.0/?c=60dcd8c53ba0f68e2d162a90&t=44027b4de63d924

I would like to scrape:
Hover green bar for 2011 and get "Credits 6.6B".
Hover blue bar for 2011 and get "Debits 9.48B".

Any suggestion on what I should try? Thank you

Comment: You can do it with python and the packages `requests` to obtain the html, and then `beautifulsoup` to parse it, pull out the json within the `<script>` tag, which contains the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method with python.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://embed.chartblocks.com/1.0/?c=60dcd8c53ba0f68e2d162a90&t=44027b4de63d924'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

script =str(soup.find('script'))
jsonStr = re.search(r"(var chartResponse = )({.*);", script).group(2)

jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)['data']['series']


debits_data = jsonData['ds-0']['values']
credits_data = jsonData['ds-1']['values']

debits_data = [x for idx, x in enumerate(debits_data) if idx%2 == 0]
debits_df = pd.DataFrame(debits_data)
debits_df['type'] = 'Debit'

credits_df = pd.DataFrame(credits_data)
credits_df['type'] = 'Credit'

results_df = debits_df.append(credits_df, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

```
print(results_df)
              y     x    type
0    9476793016  2011   Debit
1    9789776200  2012   Debit
2   10197864252  2013   Debit
3   10639447839  2014   Debit
4   11262181013  2015   Debit
5   11859026050  2016   Debit
6   12515031664  2017   Debit
7   13437815328  2018   Debit
8   14436466583  2019   Debit
9   15179342495  2020   Debit
10   6602575885  2011  Credit
11   6960716962  2012  Credit
12   7353902696  2013  Credit
13   7658670144  2014  Credit
14   8050922524  2015  Credit
15   8469721067  2016  Credit
16   8974604919  2017  Credit
17   9532204297  2018  Credit
18  10313095156  2019  Credit
19  11611223625  2020  Credit
```